# Is Transformer multi-headed attention a form of ensemble?

Tags: transformers, attention

In Transformer, is it correct to say that multi-headed attention is an ensemble learning and each head is learning a different capability by below?

1. independent random weight initialization for each head and
2. attending only to 512/8 dimension per head (where 8 is number of heads)

If incorrect, please help correct what is incorrect?

### References

[Attention Is All You Need](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762)

> #### 3.2.2 Multi-Head Attention
>
> Instead of performing a single attention function with dmodel-dimensional keys, values and queries,
> we found it beneficial to linearly project the queries, keys and values h times with different, learned
> linear projections to dk, dk and dv dimensions, respectively. On each of these projected versions of
> queries, keys and values we then perform the attention function in parallel, yielding dv-dimensional
> output values. These are concatenated and once again projected, resulting in the final values, as
> depicted in Figure 2.
> [image]

[Transformers Explained Visually (Part 3): Multi-head Attention, deep dive](https://towardsdatascience.com/transformers-explained-visually-part-3-multi-head-attention-deep-dive-1c1ff1024853)

[image]

[What is different in each head of a multi-head attention mechanism?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/25149/45763)

[image]

Comment: ensemble usually is associated with "taking N high variance predictors, and increasing the bias taking as prediction some combination of the N predictors output", for example the majority or the mean.... here there is no notion of "reducing the variance", actually it's probably the other way around... increasing the heads is used to increase the variance, in order to capture multiple connections (IMO)

Answer (score 1):

I would not say so. The idea behind ensembles is that the errors ML models make are in part systematic and in part random. When we train different classifiers for ensembling, we assume that the random part of the error will zero out and will get a better result. All the models in the ensemble do the same thing, but with a different random error.

The intuition behind multi-headed attention is quite the opposite. It is there to allow each head to focus on a different type of information in the attention input representation. In NLP, there is a lot of literature on what the attention heads do: they can look at syntactically related words, some heads can look at surrounding words, and some heads can emulate coreference chains (see e.g., Chapter 5 of [this book](https://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/books/preview/2020-marecek_full.pdf)). When trained correctly, each head should do a different thing.